# Make Regex Match Just Once

Tags: regex, match, getattribute

I want to get first src attribute, I am using this regex but it scraping all src attribute:

```
(?<=src=").*?(?=")
```

Example:

```
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY3NjY0MTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzQ2MTc0Mw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" />
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAzODk4OTI3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzU2MTY0MzE@._V1_SX86_CR0,0,86,86_AL_.jpg" />
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNzUzNzY1NzQxM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTM0MTY0MzE@._V1_SY86_CR33,0,86,86_AL_.jpg" />
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTAxNTAwMTg0ODReQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDMzNDE2NDMx._V1_SY86_CR33,0,86,86_AL_.jpg" />
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Which language are you running?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: first src attribute => `http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY3NjY0MTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzQ2MTc0Mw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the value of first `img src` attribute in two ways.

1. Through [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

   ```
   (?s)^(?:(?!<img\b[^<>]*?\bsrc=).)*<img\b[^<>]*?\bsrc="([^"]*)"
   ```

Grab the value of `img src` attribute from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uV3aL0/28)

2. Through `\K` and [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

   ```
   (?s)^(?:(?!<img\b[^<>]*?\bsrc=).)*<img\b[^<>]*?\bsrc="\K[^"]*(?=")
   ```

Grab the value of `img src` attribute from group index 0.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uV3aL0/29)

Comment: @nu11p i'm not the downvoter, but in PHP, global flag is enabled by default.

Comment: My mistake then. I have removed the answer. Thanks dude for the information :) @Avinash Raj

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?!\bsrc\b).)*src="([^"]+)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xN4qL9/3

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
  $re = "/src=[\"'](?<src>[^<>\"']+)['\"]/";
    $str = "<img src=\"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY3NjY0MTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzQ2MTc0Mw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg\" />\n<img src=\"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAzODk4OTI3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzU2MTY0MzE@._V1_SX86_CR0,0,86,86_AL_.jpg\" />\n<img src=\"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNzUzNzY1NzQxM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTM0MTY0MzE@._V1_SY86_CR33,0,86,86_AL_.jpg\" />\n<img src=\"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTAxNTAwMTg0ODReQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDMzNDE2NDMx._V1_SY86_CR33,0,86,86_AL_.jpg\" />";

    preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
    var_dump( $matches['src']);
```

**output:**

```
string 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY3NjY0MTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzQ2MTc0Mw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg' (length=114)
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/xN4qL9/6)